# How to get product IDs that follow each other in WooCommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, primary-key, auto-increment

On WooCommerce I would like to have Ids which follow each other for all my products.

But when an image is added to a product the next product ID jumps one step.

For example:

- I add a new product with 1 image and it gets **`120`** as ID (product id)…
- The image added to the product gets **`121`** as ID (thumbnail id)
- If I add a new product it gets **`122`** as ID (product id),

So product IDs doesn't follow each other… See this extract of that `wp_post` database table:

```
+-----+-------------------------------------------------+
| ID  | post_title                                      |
+-----+-------------------------------------------------+
| 963 | pot flower                                      |
| 964 | pot-flower-image1.jpg  (pot flower image)       |
| 965 | rose plant                                      |
| 966 | 51kEZ5dCM-L._SY344_BO1204203200_.jpg            |
| 967 | Pine wood                                       |
| 968 | 51xxgBTl2BtL._SX373_BO1204203200_.jpg           |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Eager to explore solutions, or some tricks.

Comment: can you elaborate more, what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @SangitaKendre Product ID is autoincrement id its across post types, meaning product id is id used to identify any post type, it could be product, images, and so on. Since i add image to a product, the image is also given ID, and its id is id of the product + 1, So the next product gets image id + 1,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't change auto-increment** as this behavior is related to MySQL for `wp_posts` table, which `ID` is the auto-increment index used by WordPress **pages**, **blog post**, **Images**… and by all **custom post types** as WooCommerce `shop_order`, `refund_order`, `coupon`, `product`, `product_variations`...

So if you want **products which Ids follow each other**, there is 2 ways:

1. Add all related images first in Wordpress Media library, then your products
2. Add all your products without images first, and add/set images afterward.